# What does CCITT stand for?

Tags: crc, crc16, acronym

In the context of the 16-bit [Cyclic Redundancy Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (CRC-16) CCITT algorithm, which uses the generator polynomial `x¹⁶ + x¹² + x⁵ + 1`, **what does "[CCITT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#cite_ref-koop04_11-7)" stand for?** I can't seem to find this initialism written out in full.

Comment: [CCITT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-T).

Comment: Look at section 2 of [t-rec-v.41-198811-.pdf](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-V.41-198811-I!!PDF-E&type=items).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CCITT stands for Consultative Committee for International Telephony and Telegraphy, which has now become the ITU-T.

https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/CCITT

Comment: How does this relate to this particular CRC-16 algorithm? The wiki you attached reads "*CCITT is a 5 tone selcall system for VHF/UHF radios.*" That doesn't sound like CRC at all. Am I missing some historical reasoning?

Comment: THere has only ever been one CCITT in the world. They published the standard for CRC, as well as for many, many, other things. The fact that the linked page is focussed on some of the other things is indeed slightly distracting, but I wanted to attribute the source.